# How to center content and make the background cover the full column when using CSS Grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

When I add this code:

```
place-items: center;
```

My elements center, but only the text has a background-color applied.

When I remove this code:

```
place-items: center;
```

The background-color covers the whole column but the text isn't centered anymore.

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  place-items: center;
}

p {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <main>
  <p>box1</p>
  <p>box2</p>
  <p>box3</p>
  <p>box4</p>
 </main>
</body>
```

Why is this happening? How can I center the content and have the background color apply to the whole column?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Without `place-items: center;` your grid items will get stretched to cover all the area (the default behavior in most of the cases) that's why the background will the cover a big area:

[image]

With `place-items: center;` your grid item will fit their content and they will be placed in the center; thus the background will cover only the text.

[image]

To avoid this, you can center **the content** inside the `p` (your grid item) instead of centering the `p`. Don't forget to also remove the default margin to cover a bigger area:

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
  place-items: stretch; /* this is the default value in most of the cases so it can be omitted */
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

p {
  background-color: #eee;
  /* center the content (you can also use flexbox or any common solution of centering) */
  display: grid; /* OR inline-grid */
  place-items: center;
  /**/
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>box1</p>
  <p>box2</p>
  <p>box3</p>
  <p>box4</p>
</main>
```

Comment: When I use display:grid; instead of display:inline-grid; , I get the same result. Which one is better to use? And why? Why did you use display:inline-grid; here?

Comment: @GalibHasanov In this case both behave the same ... the difference is exactly like block and inline-block ... if you use inline-grid with sibling elements they will be placed in the same line unlike grid ... so here you change to grid also since each element is inside a grid area alone

Comment: It may be worth mentioning in the answer that the children elements need `display: grid` or `display: inline-grid` as your comment mentions; it's important info, but comments are transient.

Comment: Awesome answer: explanation of the problem and an alternative working solution. Thanks!