# What kind of display are the direct child elements of a container using display: grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, grid-layout

If there is just a `p` tag in the HTML that has a background color of blue, and has `margin: auto`, then it takes up the width of the page, and the width and padding can be changed, like an inline-block.

```css
p {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

But if I add a parent `div` to the `p` tag, and make the `div` be `display: grid`, with `grid-template-columns: 1fr`, then the blue background only takes up the width of the text.

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

p {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

So, does `display: grid` make the child elements have `display: inline-block`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Using `display: grid` does not make the child elements `display: inline-block`.

When you set an element to `display: grid` or `inline-grid` you establish a *grid formatting context*. This is a unique layout structure with its own set of rules. The fact that some behaviors coincide with behaviors in a *block formatting context* is incidental.

The `display` value of grid items is governed by the grid container. In fact, it doesn't matter what the value says (in browser inspectors) or what the author declares (you can set the `display` to anything you want), those values are ignored and the ultimate behavior is controlled by the grid container.

The `display` value of flex items operates in the same way.

More details:

- CSS Grid Spec: [§ 6.1. Grid Item Display](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-item-display)
- CSS Flexbox Spec: [§ 4. Flex Items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)

Comment: I think the question is not well asked. The OP seems to link any *shrink-to-fit* behavior wilth inline-block, so whenever we have an element that fit its content width it should necessarely be inline-block which not the case. I think it worth explaining why using the configuration he described lead us to that output where the background is only around text.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I generally try to post answers that serve the general interest, not just the OP. The `display` value of grid items is often the subject of mystery or confusion. Hopefully, my answer helps clarify the issue. (Also, the question has been changed substantially since I posted my answer.)

Comment: yes all good if we consider the question/answer as stated but I am trying to be in the mind of the OP (and other users) They are probably not understanding why the shrink-to-fit behavior is happening that lead them to think we are dealing with inline-block (the confusion you talked about) ... By the way I remember you have an answer about this, will try to find it

Comment: If I cover one angle, and you cover the other angle, we cover both interpretations and all visitors benefit ;-) @TemaniAfif

Comment: well I found an answer of mine, here is what I meant https://stackoverflow.com/a/50841453/8620333 .. the explanation that centring (like using margin) will shrink the element. (I am pretty sure I saw one of yours similar to this with more details)

Comment: @Michael-B So, essentially it has a unique type of display, like an img tag?

Comment: It has a unique type of `display` *behavior*. The actual value may say (in browser inspectors) `block` or `flex` or something else. But the behavior wouldn't be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Left and right `auto` margin values behave differently under the contexts of flexed or grid elements. It will collapse an element entirely to its intrinsic width rather than allowing it to expand as expected.

This is similar behavior to what `inline-block` display values would produce but the element in question is crucially not `inline-block` as you suspected.

```css
div {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

p {
   background-color: blue;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have fixed the problem in the question, margin: auto has to be on the p tag.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you described:

```css
p {
    background-color: blue;
    margin: auto;
}

div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <p>Some content goes here...</p>
</div>
```

Here is the code with `display: inline-block`:

```css
p {
    background-color: blue;
    margin: auto;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <p>Some content goes here...</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, the results are slightly different. If you were to inspect the console and select the grid, it will still be the entire width of the screen because you have only set 1 column. However, the blue background will only be in a fraction of that element. When you use `margin: auto` on an item inside of the grid, it will center itself inside, acting like a container.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    p
    {
      background-color: blue;
      margin: auto;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
          <p>This is the p tag</p>
    </div>
      
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yes it is effecting if you keep margin: auto property on child element , so it is not about inline-block property , margin property making <p> tag to  takeup the width of text ..